# Rails: validate by calling class method of other class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a lot of models that contains a field called `source_name`. I need to implement a validator in each of them that will check if the `source_name` lives up to curtain conditions.

Now I also have another class called `SourceNameManager`. In this model I have a method called `valid_source_name?` which takes a `source_name_name` and returns `true` or `false`.

What is the simplest way to make a validation that just validates `source_name` by calling the external service class `SourceNameManager.valid_source_name?('some_name')`.

I was thinking about something like:

```
validates :source_name, ->(record) { SourceNameManager.valid_source_name?(record.source_name) }
```

but I don't think that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file `app/models/source_name_validator.rb`:

```
class SourceNameValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    unless SourceNameManager.valid_source_name?(value)
      record.errors[attribute] << 'is not valid'
    end
  end
end
```

Then in each model where you want to validate the source name, add:

```
validates :source_name, source_name: true
```